# I cannot access my domain after delegation in Azure

Tags: azure, dns, delegation, namecheap

after changing name servers in my registered domain (in namecheap) which has the name for example "contoso.net" to name servers, which matches the four nameservers in my Azure DNS zone (ex: ns1-08.azure-dns.com) I could not access my website as usual , and I receive the error message, which referes to the this problem with name servers (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN).
so, when I reset again the default name server to "namecheap web hosting DNS", then I can again access the website.
can anyone help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the name server for that domain to Azure provider name server, actually you have delegated that domain to Azure DNS name servers and you could edit your DNS records in the Azure DNS zone.

In this case, you need to add `A` or `CNAME` records mapping to your website's hostname or IP address in your original domain provider, then you will access websites again. Usually, it takes about a few minutes or hours for the DNS propagation. If you still could not access the websites after verifying the DNS update, please clear the cache or type `ipconfig/flushdns` on the windows command prompt.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain